# Azure Table Storage - Data Lake File - SLOW response time when fired for fetching single row Select Statement through USQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-logic-apps

Data from Transaction Database table is pulled into Data Lake, around half million records with around 20 columns, in Data Lake it is in JSON format.

Through Logic Apps, via Python -> U-SQL function, firing U-SQL statement to read particular row, response is slow, looking for improving performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of reason for the slowness when compare to local execution
1. Cluster environment is not as same as local. On cluster you have only 2 cores and 6GB of memory. Also we restrict operator to use no more than 512MB of RAM per operator. None of this issue happens on local side of the world.
2. There is an marshaling overhead and then creating dataframe when going form usql operator to python extension and via versa once you are done with the python execution
3. We need to also create an environment on the container which will be executing python code which includes copying the python run time

We are going to address 2 and 3 limitation in upcoming release in Jan 2018.